# connecting sqli database to recyclerView

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-recyclerview, android-sqlite

I made a material book which included a Recycler view that loaded from my sqli database 
 I did everything which it needed but when i start the app it gave me some  differents error :
first it gaves me this `no such table: tbl_heros (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM tbl_heros WHERE fav==1`
and then when i change the type from data base it said that 
it cant initialize my code (This 4 which i used for connecting my database and i call theme here but it dont work .. ) : 
    `selectHeros();
        selectItem();
        selectFav();
        selectAll();`

and here is the main activity codes

```
public class ActivityMain extends AppCompatActivity {

TabLayout tabLayout;
ViewPager viewPager;
DrawerLayout drawer;
NavigationView navigationView;
ImageView imgToolbar;

public static ArrayList<Heros> herosArrayList=new ArrayList<>();
public static ArrayList<Heros> itemArrayList =new ArrayList<>();
public static ArrayList<Heros> favArrayList=new ArrayList<>();
public static ArrayList<Heros> heroItemArrayList=new ArrayList<>();
public static SQLiteDatabase database;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.navigation_menu);

    drawer=(DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    navigationView=(NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.navigation) ;

    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            int id=item.getItemId();
            if(id==R.id.serch){
                Intent intent=new Intent(G.context,ActivitySearch.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
            if(id==R.id.setting){
                Intent intent=new Intent(G.context,ActivitySetting.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }if(id==R.id.hero){
                //   Intent intent=new Intent(G.context,Test.class);
                //  startActivity(intent);

            }
            return true;
        }
    });

    tabLayout=(TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    viewPager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    imgToolbar=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgToolbar);
    imgToolbar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
        }
    });

    selectHeros();
    selectItem();
    selectFav();
    selectAll();

    for(int i=0;i<herosArrayList.size();i++) {
        Log.i("LOG","id:"+herosArrayList.get(i).getInt()+"name:"+herosArrayList.get(i).getName() );
    }

    viewPager.setAdapter(new AdapterFragment(getSupportFragmentManager()));

    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}



public void selectHeros(){

    database=SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(G.direction +"/material_book.sqlite",null);
    Cursor cursor=database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_heros WHERE fav==1",null);

    while(cursor.moveToNext()){
        int id=cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("id"));
        String name=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
        String desc=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("desc"));
        String pic=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("pic"));
        String type=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("type"));
        int fav=cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("fav"));
        Heros heros=new Heros(id,name,desc,pic,fav,type);
        herosArrayList.add(heros);
        Log.i("LOG","heros check----id:"+name);

    }

}

public static  void selectItem(){

    database=SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(G.direction +"/material_book.sqlite",null);
    Cursor cursor=database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_heros WHERE type='item'",null);

    while(cursor.moveToNext()){
        int id=cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("id"));
        String name=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
        String desc=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("desc"));
        String pic=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("pic"));
        String type=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("type"));
        int fav=cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("fav"));
        Heros heros=new Heros(id,name,desc,pic,fav,type);
        itemArrayList.add(heros);

    }

}

public static  void selectFav(){

    database=SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(G.direction +"/material_book.sqlite",null);
    Cursor cursor=database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_heros WHERE fav=1",null);

    while(cursor.moveToNext()){
        int id=cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("id"));
        String name=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
        String desc=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("desc"));
        String pic=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("pic"));
        String type=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("type"));
        int fav=cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("fav"));
        Heros heros=new Heros(id,name,desc,pic,fav,type);
        favArrayList.add(heros);

    }

}

public static void selectAll() {
    database = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(G.direction + "/material_book.sqlite", null);
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_heros", null);

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("id"));
        String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
        String desc = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("desc"));
        String pic = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("pic"));
        String type = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("type"));
        int fav = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("fav"));
        Heros heros = new Heros(id, name, desc, pic, fav, type);
        heroItemArrayList.add(heros);
    }
}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(!herosArrayList.isEmpty()){
        herosArrayList.clear();
        selectHeros();

    } if(!itemArrayList.isEmpty()){
        itemArrayList.clear();
        selectItem();

    }if(!favArrayList.isEmpty()){
        favArrayList.clear();
        selectFav();

    }if(!heroItemArrayList.isEmpty()){
        heroItemArrayList.clear();
        selectAll();

    }

}

 }
```

`

Comment: Where is your DBHandler Class `class DBhandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper ` ????

Comment: post your database class also, it is impossible to reach to a solution by only this codes

Comment: I dont have such this class which extends from SQLiteOpenHelper or sth like this

Comment: I am new to android can i post all my source code ?

Comment: Are you sure that it is ok to write: 'fav==1'

Comment: i forgot to change it the correct one is fav=1 but here i sand the incorrect one , i think the problem is for somewhere else because i re run the app with fav=1 but it gaves me the same error